# String include assertion without parentheses with ScalaTest Matchers

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

On http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246279 I've found that the following assertions should work:

```
string should startWith substring "Hello"
string should endWith substring "world"
string should include substring "seven"
```

However, this doesn't compile

```
Error:(15, 29) value substring is not a member of MyTest.this.ResultOfStartWithWordForString
    string should startWith substring "Hello"
```

Is it possible to write string include assertion without using parentheses?

Comment: Your problem is not `include`, the problem is the `substring`, as you can see in the error message, it fails on the first assertion already. I think you must use `string should startWith substring("Hello") etc.

Comment: With parentheses I get the same error, it doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's no such thing as `substring` allowed after `include` or other string matchers in current versions of Scalatest. Perhaps the article you're mentioning was describing a very old version of the library.
You can either go for

```
string should include("Hello")
```

for substring matching or

```
string should include regex("Hello\\s+")
```

for regex matching.

And answering your parentheses question - Scalatest DSL is limited in this aspect that only expressions consisting of odd amount of subexpressions can be written without parentheses.

Thus, the following two assertions are valid:

```
string should include("Hello")
string should not include "Hello"
```